# AWS: List Cognito Users within Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to access the AWS Cognito UserPool from a Lambda function. The function is configured as the pool's `PreSignUp` trigger. Here is my lambda code (note, that I'm developing with TypeScript):

```
import { CognitoUserPoolEvent, Handler, Context, Callback } from 'aws-lambda';
import { CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } from 'aws-sdk';

export const onPreSignUp: Handler =
  (event: CognitoUserPoolEvent, context: Context, cb: Callback | undefined) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    const userAttr = event.request.userAttributes || undefined;
    console.log(userAttr);

    if (cb) {
      const cognitoPoolId = process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID;
      const email = userAttr.email || userAttr['cognito:email_alias'];

      if (!cognitoPoolId) {
        console.warn('No user pool id defined', cognitoPoolId);
        return cb(new Error('Can not create user'));
      }

      const identityService = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

      const params = {
        UserPoolId: cognitoPoolId,
        Filter: `email = "${email}"`,
      };

      console.log("try to list users", params);
      identityService.listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
        console.log('list users');
        if (err) {
          console.warn('listUsers Error', err);
          return cb(new Error('Can not create user'));
        }
        console.log("data", data);
        return cb(null, 'todo');
      });
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately the callback of `listUsers` never returns. If I pass an invalid `params` object, the callback returns immediately.

I've also tried to set the lambdas timeout to max (5 minutes) and increasing the RAM. Nothing helps. The lambda execution role has the `AmazonCognitoReadOnly`, which gives full read access. I would also expect a authorization error if this would be a problem.

EDIT: Right after I had posted this I've solved my problem: the lambda was configured to run within a VPC. Setting VPC to none solved it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I was not considering the VPC neither!

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me:

```
module.exports.getUserByAttribute = async (attributeName, attributeValue) => {
  const params = {
      UserPoolId: process.env.userPoolId,
      Filter: `${attributeName} = "${attributeValue}"`,
  }
  try {
      const data = await cognitoIdentityService.listUsers(params).promise()
      const existingUser = data.Users.filter(user => user.UserStatus !== 'EXTERNAL_PROVIDER')[0]
      if (existingUser == null) {
          console.log('Error', 'User not found')
      }
      return existingUser
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: getUserByAttribute', error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code should work, yes. I hope it helps others. My initial problem was the configuration of a VPC and missing NatGateway for the lambda, so it was not able to access Cognito.